# Android: Google MapView within ViewFlipper

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

I have a layout which uses a ViewFlipper to keep a tabbar visible at all times throughout the app.

The main activity extends TabActivity. For one of my views I want to have a mapview, I have tried this code to no success:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/layout_tab_one"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ListView android:id="@+id/listview" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="myapikey">
                  </com.google.android.maps.MapView>  
                <ListView android:id="@+id/lazylistview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/detail" />
                <ListView android:id="@+id/listview2" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </ViewFlipper>
```

The app crashes on launch. I have put the user library for google maps into the manifest and I am also running the app using the Google API, still no luck.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: what error you got in logcat?

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(611): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

Comment: Add ur whole stacktrace. It might help others to figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your device or emulator does not have Google Maps, or possibly you are inflating this layout from something other than a `MapActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use extends FragmentActivity on the activity where your ViewFlipper is initialised

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>           
        </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and use below code

```
int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());  

        if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { 
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, (Activity) context, 1122).show();
            return;
        }
```